# jQuery - check If one array item is same with variable

Tags: jquery, arrays

My goal is display alert message if varible test is the same as the one item of the array active.

```
<p id="user">Steve Jobs</p>

var test = $("#user").text();

var active = [
  "Steve Jobs",
  "Steve Wozniak",
  "Tim Cook"
]

if ( test === active ) {
  alert ("match");
}
```

How can I make it? Why my script doesn't work?

Comment: [Google it first](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+how+to+find+if+an+array+contains+a+value&oq=javascript+how+to+find+if+an+array+contains+a+value&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.11567j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=utf-8&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: "*Why my script doesn't work?*" - your script *does* work, it's just that `test` does not exactly equal `active`; because one is a string and the other is an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @Karolina Ticha: Were you able to resolve this? If so, please remember to accept an answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are testing whether "Steve Jobs" is identical to the array active. You could use $.inArray(test, active); to determine whether "Steve Jobs" is in the active array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = $("#user").text();

var active = [
  "Steve Jobs",
  "Steve Wozniak",
  "Tim Cook"
]

if ( $.inarray(test, active) >= 0 ) {
  alert ("match");
}
```

$.inarray() returns the index of the value that has a match.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript to check an array having a value or not we can use funcion $.inArray(). Please look in to below code.

```
<p id="user">Steve Jobs</p>

var test = $("#user").text();

var active = [
  "Steve Jobs",
  "Steve Wozniak",
  "Tim Cook"
]

if ($.inArray( test, active )) {
  alert ("match");
}
```

Comment: I have checked code.Please use following condition it will work.
if ($.inArray( test, active )>=0) {
  console.log ("match");
}